# How can i solve $\lim _{x\to +\infty } \left(\frac{3+x^{\alpha}}{2+x}\right)^{x}$ without de L'Hopital?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm having some trouble with this limit:

$$\lim _{x\to +\infty } \left(\frac{3+x^{\alpha}}{2+x}\right)^{x}$$

The parameter $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. I've tried dividing the problem in three different cases: $\alpha = 1, \alpha < 1$ and $\alpha > 1$. For the first two the calculation looks pretty easy, as I, first, rewrite both numerator and denominator as the well known limit $(\theta/x + 1)^x \to e^\theta$:
$$\frac{\left( 3 + x \right)^x}{\left( 2 + x \right)^x} = \frac{\left( 3/x + 1 \right)^x}{\left( 2/x + 1 \right)^x}\to \frac{e^3}{e^2} = e .$$

Then I see that for $\alpha > 1$:
$$\left(\frac{3}{x^\alpha}+1\right)^x = \left(\frac{3}{x^\alpha} + 1 \right)^{x^\alpha x^{1-\alpha}}\to e^{3x^{1-\alpha}}\to1$$ and $$\left(\frac{2}{x^\alpha}+x^{1-\alpha}\right)^x \to 0.$$

The $\alpha < 1$ case, instead, gives me the indeterminate form $\frac\infty\infty$, which I'm unable to solve. This exercise is given in the "known limits" sections so I guess I can solve it without using de L'Hopital.

Comment: @Troposphere sorry there was a typo: it is $1-\alpha$ not $\alpha - 1$. So it gives a negative exponent, therefore it goes to zero as the first term in the parenthesis.

Comment: hopItal not hopYtal

Answer (score 1):

If $\alpha <1$,

$$\begin{align}\lim _{x\to \infty } \left(\frac{3+x^{\alpha}}{2+x}\right)^{x}
&=\lim _{x\to \infty } \left(\frac{\frac 3x+x^{\alpha-1}}{\frac 2x+1}\right)^{x}\\
&=\lim _{x\to \infty } \left(x^x\right)^{\alpha -1}\\
&=\lim _{x\to \infty } \frac{1}{\left(x^x\right)^{1-\alpha}}=0.
\end{align}$$

Comment: For $\alpha>1 $ case you can do with the same way. $\alpha=1$ case is trivial.

Comment: The second equals sign here seems iffy -- in particular if $\alpha<0$, then $3/x$ is going to to dominate over $x^{\alpha-1}$. Better just to say that the entire fraction obviously goes to $0$, so raising to ever larger powers will only make it go to $0$ _faster_.

Comment: @Troposphere we dont need $\alpha <0$. We need $1-\alpha >0$.

Comment: Your calculation is presented as working for all $\alpha<1$. For example, for $\alpha=-6$ it seems that you're claiming that $$ \lim \left(\frac{3x^{-1} + x^{-7}}{2x^{-1}+1}\right)^x = \lim (x^x)^{-7}$$ What justifies the $-7$ on the right here? The conclusion is _true_ because both sides are $0$, but the _reasoning_ in this step is pretty opaque to me.

Comment: @Troposphere Yes, limit equals to zero.

Comment: Please make comment. Why downvote?

Comment: The numerator $(3/x+x^{\alpha-1})^x$ is less than $(3/x+1/2)^x$ for $x$ sufficiently large if $\alpha < 1$.  Rewriting as $(1/2)^x (6/x+1)^x$, we see this is a product of a term tending to zero and a bounded term (approaching $e^6$).  Therefore, the numerator tends to zero. The denominator is bounded.  Therefore, the limit on the right-hand side of the first equality approaches zero.

Answer (score 1):

<s>This step in your reasoning is not valid:</s>

$$\left(\frac{3}{x^\alpha}+1\right)^x \to e^{x^{1-\alpha}}\to1$$

I assume your point is something like first rewrite $\left(\dfrac{3}{x^\alpha}+1\right)^x$ to $\left(\dfrac{3x^{1-\alpha}}{x}+1\right)^x$ (where did the 3 go, by the way?). However, the fact that you rely on next,
$$ \Bigl(1+\frac{\theta}{x}\Bigr)^x \to e^\theta \qquad\text{when }x\to\infty $$
is only valid when $\theta$ is a constant! Here it actually depends on $x$, and it is not reliable reasoning to let only *some* of the $x$s in the limit go to $\infty$ first and then handle the rest later.

If we could do that, we could -- with the same justification -- decide to let the denominator in $\frac xx$ go to $\infty$ first and erroneously conclude
$$ 1 = \frac xx = \frac1x\cdot x \to 0\cdot x \to 0 $$
as $x\to\infty$.

---

This is a case where trying to shoehorn your reasoning into purely symbolic rewrites makes things *harder*. In fact the $\alpha>1$ and $\alpha<1$ cases are both pretty easy:

- Suppose $\alpha>1$. Then $\frac{3+x^\alpha}{2+x}=\frac{3/x+x^{\alpha-1}}{2/x+1} \to \infty$ and therefore from a certain point onwards -- say, for $x>M$ -- we always have
  $\frac{3+x^\alpha}{2+x}>2$. Therefore when $x>\max(M,0)$ we have
  $$ \Bigl(\frac{3+x^\alpha}{2+x}\Bigr)^x > 2^x $$
  which goes to $+\infty$.
- Suppose $\alpha<1$. Then the numerator of $\frac{3/x+x^{\alpha-1}}{2/x+1}$ goes to $0$ while the denominator goes to $1$, so from a certain point we always have $\frac{3+x^\alpha}{2+x}<\frac12$. Thus, from a certain point we'll have
  $$ \Bigl(\frac{3+x^\alpha}{2+x}\Bigr)^x < (1/2)^x $$
  which just as easily goes to $0$.

The only complicated case is $\alpha=1$. Then we have $\frac{3+x^\alpha}{2+x}\to 1$, and neither of the above tricks will make progress. Then *and only then* is it time to be clever:
$$ \Bigl(\frac{3+x}{2+x}\Bigr)^x = \Bigl(1+\frac{1}{2+x}\Bigr)^x
= \Bigl(1+\frac{1}{2+x}\Bigr)^{2+x}\Bigl(1+\frac{1}{2+x}\Bigl)^{-2} $$
Now switching variable to $t=x+2$ we have
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}\Bigl(\frac{3+x}{2+x}\Bigr)^x
= \lim_{t\to\infty} (1+\tfrac1t)^t(1+\tfrac1t)^{-2}
= \big[\lim_{t\to\infty} (1+\tfrac1t)^t\big]\big[\lim_{t\to\infty}(1+\tfrac1t)^{-2}\big]
= e\cdot 1 = e $$

Comment: $$\left(\frac{3+x}{2+x}\right)^{x}=\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{x+2}\right)^{x+2}\right)^{\frac{x}{x+2}}$$

Comment: @lonestudent: That works too.

Comment: As you correctly pointed out I forgot the 3 at the exponent, but the calculation looks correct to me. I've added a few steps to make it clearer. Can you tell me if they're wrong?

Comment: @caccolona: Ah, now I see what you were going for. That's valid, just confusingly written because it looks like you're taking the limits of the base and the exponent one at time; they should really be done in parallel.